# ListView.getSelectionModel().selectIndices OOB bug?

Tags: javafx, java-9, javafx-9

I have a ListView and want to select multiple indices programmatically inside `Platform.runLater()`

Problem: If the indices I want to select are sequential (e.g. `{5,6,7}`) the selection works fine. If there is a gap (e.g. `{5,7,8}`), an OOB exception is thrown.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: [ fromIndex: 0, toIndex: 5, size: 3 ]
```

I believe there may be a bug in Java9's (this exception started appearing after we upgraded from Java8 to 9) `MultipleSelectionModelBase#set`.

For the indices `{5,6,7}`, the method calls `_nextAdd(from, to)` with the values 0 and 3. (0 inclusive, 3 exclusive, with I assume refers to the indices 0,1,2 in my array of `{5,6,7}`)

For the indices `{5,7,8}`, it calls `_nextAdd(0,2)` for `{5}` and `_nextAdd(2,5)` for the indices `{7,8}`.
I believe it should instead be `_nextAdd(0,1)` and `_nextAdd(1,3)` since my array has only 3 elements, not 5.

The exception is eventually thrown when `javafx.collections.ListChangeListener#getAddedSubList` calls `getList().subList(getFrom(), getTo())` with the parameters 0,5

I googled for bug reports and could not find anything about this problem.
I thought I'd ask here before filing a bug report.

MVCE

Start the program, click on the "Select 578" button. 
An exception is thrown (and caught): [ fromIndex: 0, toIndex: 5, size: 3 ]

OR

Comment out both "clearSelection" lines.
Start the program, click on "Select 567", then click on "Select 578".
An exception is thrown (and caught): [ fromIndex: 8, toIndex: 9, size: 4 ]

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten");
        ListView<String> list = new ListView<>(items);
        list.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        Button select567Button = new Button();
        select567Button.setText("Select 567");
        select567Button.setOnAction(event -> {
            list.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            list.getSelectionModel().selectIndices(5, 6, 7);
        });

        Button select578Button = new Button();
        select578Button.setText("Select 578");
        select578Button.setOnAction(event -> {
            list.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            list.getSelectionModel().selectIndices(5, 7, 8);
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(select567Button, select578Button, list);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Java -version

```
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)
```

StackTrace (when starting the program and immediately selecting "578" Button before anything else):

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: [ fromIndex: 0, toIndex: 5, size: 3 ]
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:170)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(ListChangeListener.java:242)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior.lambda$new$55(ListViewBehavior.java:281)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList._endChange(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:63)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase$SelectedIndicesList._endChange(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:895)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase$SelectedIndicesList.set(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:785)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.selectIndices(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:490)
    at sample.Main.lambda$start$1(Main.java:33)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8863)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:189)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Comment: Could you update the question with an exact block of code to reproduce this?

Comment: updated to include an MVCE

Comment: That looks like a bug: I recommend you report it [here](https://bugreport.java.com/).

Comment: sounds similar to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8197985 - there are many more .. though it's improving .. sloooowwwwly